# ASP.NET Core controller return "success" box instead of view and stay on the same page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web

I am making an ASP.NET core mailfunction, in the process I submit a form to my HomeController that sends a mail and returns view. I get redirected to the view, is there a way to stay on the same page instead of looking for a view im localhost/Home/View? Here is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMailService mailService;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IToastNotification _toastNotification;


        public HomeController(IMailService mailService,
            ILogger<HomeController> logger,
            IToastNotification toastNotification)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _toastNotification = toastNotification;
            this.mailService = mailService;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMail([FromForm] MailTemplate request)
        {
            try
            {
                await mailService.SendEmailAsync(request);
                _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Message Sent Successfully");
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my Startup Endpoint:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
```

Thanks beforehand!

Best regards Max

Comment: Yes, you can. You can update a page without leaving the page - look into techniques like AJAX, HTTP Fetch API etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some library like `NToastNotify`.

Install the package

```
Install-Package NToastNotify
```

And configure it in the startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNToastNotifyNoty();

app.UseNToastNotify();
```

Add this in _Layout page:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")
```

Dependency inject IToastNotification to HomeController

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly IToastNotification _toastNotification;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IToastNotification toastNotification)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _toastNotification = toastNotification;
}
```

Then Add the message in the form post action, and return to your current View.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string emailAddress)
{
    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Message Sent Successfully");
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It sort of works, I get redirected to a View thats localhost/Home but when I go back to localhost I get the message. How do I stay on the same page when submit?

Comment: Directly redirect to Index in the SendMail action. `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery and Ajax, in your `HomeController`

```
  public JsonResult SendEmail(string address,string content)
        {
          bool response;
          //send email
          return Json(response);
        }
```

in `View`

```
   var url = '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "Home")'
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { address: $("#addresstextboxid").val(),content:$("#hometextboxid").val()},
            success: function (response) {
               // Whatever you want to do with response
            }
        });
```